# What is special about Knockout's automatic view update?

Tags: knockout.js

I am learning Knockout.js, and I have a fundamental question, which may sound silly but it's really bugging me for quite a while.

According to official website, one of the main feature of Knockout.js is:

***Elegant dependency tracking - automatically updates the right parts of your UI whenever your data model changes.***

I understand how that works. (Correct me below if I am wrong in any part.)

Basically, if I have following View:

```
<h1 data-bind="text: name"></h1>
<p data-bind="text: status"></p>
```

and following ViewModel:

```
function FlightVM () {
    this.name = ko.observable("Boieng 120");
    this.status = ko.observable("In Air");
}

ko.applyBindings(new FlightVM());
```

If I change my data somewhere, it will automatically  update the corresponding html. This I understand well.

My question is, what is different in here than just setting my data in the View as follows:

```
var name = "Boieng 120";
$("h1").html(name);
```

Here also, if I change the name, and refresh the page, it will update the html dynamically. What advantage does Knockout give us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The accepted answer here falls somewhat short of a complete answer.

Your understanding of what "dependency tracking" actually means is incorrect. What you describe is actually just the data-binding part of knockoutjs. This functionality is very common and is replicated in many ways by many other frameworks.

Dependency tracking is where knockout becomes much, much cleverer.

Say you have two observables:

```
var firstName = ko.observable("akshay");
var lastName = ko.observable("Khot");
```

and now you make a computed observable:

```
var fullName = ko.computed(function(){return firstName()+" "+lastName();});
```

Now let's make a model:

```
var model = {
    firstName:firstName,
    lastName:lastName,
    fullName:fullName
}
```

and bind it:

```
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

to the following HTML:

```
<span data-bind="text:fullName"></span>
```

Now, because dependency tracking has calculated that `fullName` depends on `firstName` and `lastName`, when you update either of these values:

```
model.lastName("is cool");
```

then the notifications from the dependencies of `model.fullName` will cause the value of `model.fullName` to change, and for this value to be updated in the DOM (so it now reads `akshay is cool`), even though the DOM is not bound to `lastName`, only something that depends on `lastName`.

Pretty neat when you think about it and a feature that keeps me coming back to KO as my goto framework.

If this leaves you curious as to how it all works...

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-dependency-tracking.html

and

http://www.knockmeout.net/2014/05/knockout-dependency-detection.html

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer. Makes it clear, and this feature is pretty neat. Thanks.